# Excel developer list box dimensions are not preserved

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, forms, activex

I used the Excel Developer Tab to create a List Box for a macro. Every time I open the file my List Box is in, the list box has shrunk. I need help fixing the width and height of the List Box such that whenever I open this file the box will preserve its dimensions and location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveX List Box Controls have a property called IntegralHeight. Once set to False, the List Box will stop auto re-sizing.